# Using manipulate with a defined funtion to solve a ODE

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate, warning-messages

As many in this community I'm new in *Mathematica* and while exploring the numerical solver for differential equations, I tried:

```
clc;
denshi[g_, k_, h_, vo_, t_] := 
  NDSolve[{w''[t] - g - k*Exp[-w[t]/h] w'[t] == 0, w[0] == 0, 
    w'[0] == vo}, w, t];
Manipulate
[Plot[denshi[g, k, h, vo, t], {t, 0, 34}, PlotRange -> 10], {g, 0, 
  20}, {k, 0, 10}, {h, 0, 10}, {vo, 0, 10}]
```

But the program says more input is required. I would appreciate a suggestion for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...is incomplete; more input is needed" is just one of your problems. "More input required" appears because you put the `[` on a different line than `Manipulate`. For example

```
Sin
[f[x]]
```

will generate the same error message. Another problem is that `NDSolve` doesn't return what you think it should return. You didn't mention this, but you could have just tried for example

```
denshi[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and you would see that it returns "1 cannot be used as a variable." This is because the third argument in `NDSolve` is supposed to be of the format `{t, tmin, tmax}`. This tells `NDSolve` to return an interpolating function between `tmin` and `tmax`, instead you just put a number as the third argument. If you thought that would give you the solution at that time you thought wrong, `NDSolve` cannot be used like that. The correct way to get the value at time `tt` is this:

```
denshi[g_, k_, h_, vo_, tt_] := First[w /. NDSolve[{
       w''[t] - g - k*Exp[-w[t]/h] w'[t] == 0,
       w[0] == 0,
       w'[0] == vo
       }, w, {t, 0, tt}]][tt];
```

I recommend that you pick this expression apart and try to understand why this code works.

Even after this you get an error, or lots of errors. They are all caused by the fact because

```
Plot[denshi[g, k, h, vo, t], {t, 1, 34}]
```

redefines `t`. It gives `t` a value even inside the function `denshi`. I think it's above your current level to understand why this syntax affects `t` inside `denshi` but if you want to look it up you can read about the `Block` function, `Plot` gives its iteration variable this type of scope. So we have to change the name of that as well. The solution is to use another symbol than `t`. We end up with

```
denshi[g_, k_, h_, vo_, tt_] := First[w /. NDSolve[{
       w''[t] - g - k*Exp[-w[t]/h] w'[t] == 0,
       w[0] == 0,
       w'[0] == vo
       }, w, {t, 0, tt}]][tt];
Manipulate[
 Plot[denshi[g, k, h, vo, ttt], {ttt, 1, 34}],
 {g, 1, 20}, {k, 1, 10}, {h, 1, 10}, {vo, 1, 10}
 ]
```

where I've also changed a few starting values because there are singularities at zero.

As you posed this as if it were a question about "the numerical solver" and then had a lot of other problems, problems related to `Manipulate` and `Plot` mostly, as well as problems with `NDSolve`, I recommend that you practice with more basic problems. Start by using `NDSolve` on its own, then put it inside `Plot` and then finally when you have that working put it inside `Manipulate`.

Comment: The only possible singularity is at h=0. Anyway it was an extensive explanation of my mistakes and what to focus on, I appreciate it and will practice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 Manipulate[
    Block[{s, tmax = 10},
        s = NDSolve[{w''[t] - g - k*Exp[-w[t]/h] w'[t] == 0, w[0] == 0, 
           w'[0] == vo}, w, {t, 0, tmax}];
        Plot[w[t] /. s, {t, 0, tmax}]
    ]
  , {g, 1, 10}, {k, 1, 10}, {h, 1, 10}, {vo, 1, 10}
 ]
```

returns:

[image]